# Question regarding validation rule

Tags: validation-rule, validation

Course name, Duration, Course Fee, and category fields are all mandatory, but duration for (Java) picklist value under course name field should not be mandatory.

I have done this but still not working plz help.

```
AND(( INCLUDES (Course_Name__c , 'Java' ))
&&
ISNULL(' Duration_In_Hours__c'))
```

(this code is error-free still no working)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you put the field name in quotes:

```
ISNULL(' Duration_In_Hours__c')
```

This is always false, because the parameter is a non-null string value.

Try:

```
INCLUDES(Course_Name__c,'Java') && ISNULL(Duration_In_Hours__c)
```

Use either `AND(cond1,cond2,...,condN)` or `cond1 && cond2 && ... && condN`, but not both at the same time.